# Android Studio Bluetooth Connection (blood pressure device) data gathering

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth blood pressure measurement device. I need to get BP data from this device to my application. However I do not know anything about bluetooth connections and when I researched I found some code snippets that not worked.

Would any tutorial or sample project work for me?

I followed: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#java

But I couldn't figure it out and could not create a working application.

Comment: check your device's documentation on which protocol it uses.

Comment: it says bluetooth LE.

Comment: that is not protocol. Check what you should read from it, and what to write into it

Comment: Have you tried: https://medium.com/@avigezerit/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-22bc7310387a ? It worked for me.

Comment: yep i tried this tutorial too. Still did not get the enough info from this tutorial